# Tensorflow : serving model return always the same prediction

Tags: tensorflow, serving

I need your help I'm a little bit stuck right now.

I retrain a classification tensorflow model that gives quite nice results.
Now I want to serve it through tensorflow serving.
I managed to serve it but when i'm using it, it always gives me same results no matter what the input is.

I think there is something wrong the way I export the model but I can't figure what. Below is my code.

Can somebody help me ? Thanks a lot guys

**This is the function that transform my input image into a readable object for tf:**

```
def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name, input_height=299, input_width=299,
            input_mean=0, input_std=255):
  input_name = "file_reader"
  output_name = "normalized"
  file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
  if file_name.endswith(".png"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                   name='png_reader')
  elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
image_reader = tf.squeeze(tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader,
                                              name='gif_reader'))
  elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name='bmp_reader')
  else:
image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                    name='jpeg_reader')
  float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
  dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
  resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
  normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
  sess = tf.Session()
  result = sess.run(normalized)

  return result,normalized
```

**And this is how I export my model:**

```
  # Getting graph from the saved pb file
  graph = tf.Graph()
  graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with open(model_file, "rb") as f:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
  with graph.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

  # below, var "t" is the result of the transformation, "tf_input" a tensor before computation.
  t,predict_inputs_tensor = read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                              input_height=input_height,
                              input_width=input_width,
                              input_mean=input_mean,
                              input_std=input_std)

  input_name = "import/" + input_layer
  output_name = "import/" + output_layer

  input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
  output_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

  # Let's predict result to get an exemple output
  with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                  {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
  results = np.squeeze(results)


  # Creating labels 
  class_descriptions = []
  labels = load_labels(label_file)
  for s in labels:
    class_descriptions.append(s)
  classes_output_tensor = tf.constant(class_descriptions)      
  table = 
 tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string_table_from_tensor(classes_output_tensor)
 classes = table.lookup(tf.to_int64(labels))

  top_k = results.argsort()[-len(labels):][::-1]
  scores_output_tensor, indices =tf.nn.top_k(results, len(labels))

  # Display
  for i in top_k:
    print(labels[i], results[i])


  version=1
  path="/Users/dboudeau/depot/tensorflow-for-poets-2/tf_files"

  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('version', version, 'version number of the model.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('work_dir', path, 'your older model  directory.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('model_dir', '/tmp/magic_model', 'saved model directory')
  FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

  with tf.Session() as sess:
      classify_inputs_tensor_info = 
tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(predict_inputs_tensor)

  export_path = os.path.join(
      tf.compat.as_bytes(FLAGS.model_dir)
      ,tf.compat.as_bytes(str(FLAGS.version))
      )

  print(export_path)
  builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

  # define the signature def map here
```

predict_inputs_tensor_info=tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(predict_inputs_tensor)
classes_output_tensor_info=tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(classes_output_tensor)
scores_output_tensor_info=tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(scores_output_tensor)

```
  classification_signature = (
    tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
              inputs={
                  tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS:
                      classify_inputs_tensor_info
              },
              outputs={
                  tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES:
                      classes_output_tensor_info,
                  tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_SCORES:
                      scores_output_tensor_info
              },
              method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.
              CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME))

  prediction_signature = (
          tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
              inputs={'images': predict_inputs_tensor_info},
              outputs={
                  'classes': classes_output_tensor_info,
                  'scores': scores_output_tensor_info
              },

method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
          ))

  legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')

  # This one does'
  final_sdn={
```

tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:classification_signature,
      }

```
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
      sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
      signature_def_map=final_sdn,
      legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)

  builder.save()
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you get any progress with this ?

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same problem I have battle against for a while. In the end it turned out that I was sending Double type for a float32 in the model, and somehow tensowflow casted this double to 0 value. It means that, whatever you send via RPC, is taken to be 0 in the model. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I did 2 tests : first I check in the RPC client part, I create to proto with 2 differents images. As expected proto used as input are totally different.For me it means that the input sended to the served model is different .     
Second test was to check the tensor info that are passed to create the serving signature. Below are the values that I get. I don't see where the error you describe could occurs ?  Thanks again for your help @Ozum Safa

Comment: `>>> predict_inputs_tensor_info
name: "truediv:0"
dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 1
  }
  dim {
    size: 224
  }
  dim {
    size: 224
  }
  dim {
    size: 3
  }
}

>>> classes_output_tensor_info
name: "Const:0"
dtype: DT_STRING
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 15
  }
}

>>> scores_output_tensor_info
name: "TopKV2:0"
dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 15
  }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for a different answer, check out this answer:

[Tensorflow Serving on pretrained Keras ResNet50 model returning always same predictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469433/tensorflow-serving-on-pretrained-keras-resnet50-model-returning-always-same-pred?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I was also facing the same issue and I tried all other options, like checking preprocessing function, changing input dtype from `uint` to `float32/64`. I thought it's happening because of dropout, but then it turned out it's happening because of tensorflow's global_variables_initializer.